# Can we write a hive query in Spark - UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, user-defined-functions

Can we write a hive query in Spark - UDF.
eg I have 2 tables:
[Table A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsHOA.png)

where b1 contains column names of A and b2 contains the value of that column in A.
Now I want to query the tables in such a way that I get result as below:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiU6J.png).

Basically replace the values of column in A with B based on column names and their corresponding values.
To achieve that I wrote spark-UDF eg:convert as below

```
def convert(colname: String, colvalue:String)={
```

`sqlContext.sql("SELECT b3 from B where b1 = colname and b2 = colvalue").toString;
}`

I registered it as:

```
sqlContext.udf.register("conv",convert(_:String,_:String));
```

Now my main query is-

```
val result = sqlContext.sql("select a1 , conv('a2',a2), conv('a3',a3)");
```

result.take(2);

It gives me java.lang.NullPointerException.

Can someone please suggest if this feature is supported in spark/hive.
Any other approach is also welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: you cannot use sqlContext inside an UDF

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, UDF Doesn't permit to write a Query inside. 
You can only pass the data as variables and do transformation to get the final result back at row/column/table level.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to your question. You can do it in Hive itself.

```
WITH a_plus_col
AS (SELECT a1
        ,'a2' AS col_name
        ,a2 AS col_value
    FROM A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a1
        ,'a3' AS col_name
        ,a3 AS col_value
    FROM A)
SELECT a_plus_col.a1 AS r1
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN a_plus_col.col_name = 'a2' THEN B.b3 END) AS r2
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN a_plus_col.col_name = 'a3' THEN B.b3 END) AS r3
FROM a_plus_col
INNER JOIN B ON ( a_plus_col.col_name = b1 AND a_plus_col.col_value = b2)
GROUP BY a_plus_col.a1;
```